# How to handle a group activity during an interview when the participants are applying for the same job as you?

Tags: interviewing

A company has offered the chance for an interview.
There is only one position available (as it is a managerial position) and is in quite a 'tight-knit' industry (i.e mostly everyone knows each other).

One part of the interview is a group activity.  In this case, the other group participants are also applying for the same position as you - and you are likely to see them during this group activity.

How can one approach this group activity without 'burning-bridges' with the other applicants?

Comment: never seen such a thing with a managerial position. What does the group activity consist of?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking when she called me inviting me for the interview.  What I am assuming from reading online is that they will give you a scenario, and you need to work together as a team to solve it.  (e.g this person is stuck on the other side of the river, how can he get back to land), or something like that.  But my biggest concern is meeting the other candidates who are applying for the SAME position.  And there is only one position available!

Comment: Why does meeting the other candidates concern you? You know them all already, it's presumably not going to shock anyone that they apply for new roles as well.

Comment: Is it a sword fight, like a duel, last man standing?

Comment: Not that I know of @Daniel - I heard it's a team exercise like 'How can this person cross the river'... And as a team you need to devise methods on how this person can cross the river etc.

Comment: I like the existing answers. I'm not a manager and take this with a grain of salt, but I've noticed that in groups where people know each other there are sometimes an individual or small set of individuals which sort of *take the lead* on things. I suspect this happens because since you know each other you already formed a hierarchy in your head of "dude A knows more than me", "dudes A and B are more experienced than me". They might be trying to ascertain which of these individuals is the pack lead or the "alpha" (others look for them for cues on how to proceed...).

Answer (score 23):

You do everything you can to make the group activity a success *because the primary function of a manager is to enable their team*. If you're the person who does that, I know you're going to do the right thing when you're working in my company.

If you show any hint whatsoever that you're prepared to sacrifice the success of the group for your own personal gain, or try and take any personal credit for the actions of the group, that's one of the biggest red flags I can imagine when looking for a manager.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but way open to interpretation. is this a common technique?

Comment: But if every applicant is good and has a team-first attitude, doesn't that defeat the purpose of the group task?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen 1) No, it lets me know my pre-interview screening and/or 2) That's result bias. Just because a test didn't distinguish candidates *in this instance*, it doesn't mean it's not useful. Next time, it might let me rule out someone.

Comment: @Kilisi It's what *I* want from a leader, and the idea of a "servant leader" certainly isn't uncommon among tech companies. See e.g. *Debugging Teams* by Fitzpatrick and Collins-Sussman.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Interviews should test for the skills and character you want to employ - if every candidate is equally perfect, it means you cannot make a bad decision in who you ultimately choose. Realistically though, my experience is many people *do* become selfish, controlling and undermining in these group tasks; and they are a very effective way to filter out those kind of candidates.

Answer (score 10):

You really don't know what the interviewer expects. What Philip says is quite reasonable, but there is no guarantee that the interviewer is reasonable, so this strategy might fail. The interviewer might look for a cutthroat, backstabbing monster and if you follow Philip's advice then you are not it.

But in that case, maybe you wouldn't want to win, right? So think about what a *good* employer would want, one where you would want the job. And then you do what would make a *good* employer happy. So maybe you help the team succeed, but someone stabs you in the back. If you get the job, you're fine. If the backstabber gets the job, you had a close escape.

Comment: Yes, this. If you act like a good leader and don't get hired because of that, you just dodged a bullet.